# Snap to canvas midpoints in Gimp

Tags: gimp, snapping

What's the best approach if I want to snap to the canvas' horizontal and vertical centre points? Let's say I want to place a guide in the center of both directions for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no snap to the centre of the canvas in GIMP.  However you could modify the grid using *Image > Configure grid*, then set the horizontal and vertical values to half the image dimensions, then enable snap to grid, and view grid (if you want to see it).

Also, there's a solution for getting guides in the centre.  Click on *Image > Guides > New guide (by percent)*. The default is 50% and Horizontal. Repeat for the Vertical guide.

Comment: Thanks Billy, the second option is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If you do this often, you can use [ofn-preset-guides](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) to create sets of guides that you can add with one keystroke. Centered guides is part of the examples.